# Image sharpness goes away with drawing gradient effect on it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image (with X & 2X variants) which look sharp and clean on the retina device. But I wanted a gradient effect on it. Once I draw the gradients on it, image looses the sharpness, I guess because of gradients are not put on exact image boundaries. Any suggestion how to fix this. I am attaching the images (With and without gradient effect) as well as my gradient code:

```
- (UIImage *)tintedWithLinearGradientColors:(NSArray *)colorsArray forImageNamed:(NSString *)iImageName {
    // Load image
    UIImage *myIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:iImageName];
    // Create gradient
    UIColor *colorOne = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:1]; // top color
    UIColor *colorTwo = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:0]; // bottom color

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, (id)colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myIconImage.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, myIconImage.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, myIconImage.size.width, myIconImage.size.height);

    // image drawing code
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myIconImage.CGImage);

    // draw tint color, preserving alpha values of original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, myIconImage.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(0, myIconImage.size.height), 0);

    UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return coloredImage;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the line

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myIconImage.size);
with
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myIconImage.size, NO, myIconImage.scale);
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this gradient by code? If don't, add the gradient on photoshop or other software and then add the image to your project already with the gradient.